# How to randomly teleport players using command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to teleport a player **randomly** in a 10,000 block radius when they step on a pressure plate. How do I do this?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 3):

Try the `/spreadplayers` command, which spreads entities in a random area. The syntax is `/spreadplayers <x> <z> <spreadDistance> <maxRange> <respectTeams> <player …>`

In your case, you might want to try something like `/spreadplayers ~ ~ 0 10000 false @a[r=5,c=1]`.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `@a[distance=..5,limit=1]`